# « Vas-y fort » : détails ?

Tags: sens, locutions, québec, régionalismes, impératif

> ...fait qu’il dit euh •vas-y vas-y fort° pis c’est lui qui s’en
> occupait crisse... ([*Corpus de français parlé du Québec*](https://applis.flsh.usherbrooke.ca/cfpq/index.php/transcriptions/recherche/vas-y%20vas-y))

Ce « vas-y fort » est-il une tournure exclusive au français du Québec ? Quelle est sa nature et sa signification ?

Answer (score 1):

***Vas-y fort*** peut se dire en France mais n'est ni très courant, ni une locution contrairement à *[**Vas-y mollo**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mollo)* qui signifie justement le contraire.

Comment: J'avais jamais pensé à _mollo_ comme antonyme, oui dans certains cas ça marche, dans des trucs concrets, mais parfois non, quand l'action ne se prête pas à l'idée de force. Peut-être que finalement je vais boucler la boucle avec la question sur « vas-y » posée il y a belle lurette ! Je peux pas comprendre que le site ne l'affiche pas dans les _related_, algo douteux.